# text for Rav Kook's positive viduy?

Tags: sources-mekorot, viduy-confession, abraham-isaac-kook

It was quoted in a class that I was in once that Rav Kook has a text for a positive viduy where he takes the normal expression of sin and inverts it to talk about what we have done right. What is the text, or where can I find it online?

Comment: http://rabbifleischmann.blogspot.com/2012/09/rav-kooks-flipped-vidui.html I suspect he never actually composed one but only talked about the potential value of it.

Comment: See http://aryehbderech.blogspot.com/2015/03/rav-kooks-positive-viduy-confession.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

[image]

As shared with us earlier today by Rabbi Joseph B. Meszler:

Comment: I linked to this above. I don't see where it says Rav Kook wrote it.

Comment: Source: In Deuteronomy 26:13 (Ki Tavo) it describes a "confession" where a farmer appears and declares that they have paid all of their tithes and has not forgotten anything. This is further emphasized in the Mishnah Maaser Sheni 5:11 that the farmer has not forgotten to bless God's name. this is the Vidui Ma'aser. Kook in Ein Ayah vol. II, 405-407, which is his commentary on Ein Yaakov, talks about how we need to confess the good that we have done and not just the bad (albeit in Sotah 32b it says we should do so in a low voice so as

Comment: not be appear arrogant). This was apparently composed based on Kook's words, but I don't know by whom, and I did my best to translate it. See also: http://ravkooktorah.org/KI_TAVO_67.htm.

Answer (score 1):

The "Viduy-Hamashlim" was writen by my.
Binyamin holtzman, Rav Kibutz Ma'ale gilbo'a.

את "הוידוי המשלים" אני כתבתי.
בנימין הולצמן, רב קיבוץ מעלה גלבוע

look for בנימין הולצמן at facebook

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Rabbi Holtzman! could you perhaps provide a link to the vidduy? Thanks for the answer. Hope to see you around the site.

Answer (score -1):

This answer was given through the rabbis of the Central Conference of American Rabbis:

Ahavnu - We have loved, Bachinu - we have cried, Gamalnu - we have given back, Dibarnu Yofi - we have spoken great things! He’emanu - We have believed, V’hishtadalnu - and we have given our best effort, Zacharnu - we have remembered, Chibaknu - we have embraced, Ta’amnu sefer - we have chanted Your book! Yatzarnu - We have created, Kamanu - we have yearned, Lachamnu avur hatzedek - we have fought for justice! Mitzinu et hatov - We have done all the good we could do, Nisinu - we have tried, Sarnu lirot - we have turned aside to see, Asinu asher tzvitanu - we have done as You have commanded us! Peirashu - We have learned interpretations of Torah, Tzadaknu lifamim - sometimes we have even been righteous, Karanu b’shimcha - we have called out Your Name! Ratzinu - We have been steadfast in our will, Samachnu - we have rejoiced, Tamachnu - we have been there to support one another.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Is this the text o R' Kook's viduy or something written by the CCAR?

Comment: Can you [tell us](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/45909/edit) where you found this? Was it written in a book, found on a web page, etc.?